# Changing TAI Time epoch correctly

Tags: c++, time

Currently, I'm working on an implementation which requires a specific time two work correctly.
How the time should be encoded is described as following:

`Timestamp = Timestamp(TAI) % 2^32
where Timestamp(TAI) is the number of elapsed 
TAI milliseconds since 2004-01-01 00:00:00.000 UTC`

Now, I tried the following which basically works but I'm not sure if the output is correct.

```
timespec now;
if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_TAI, &now) == 0) {
    // tai_clock uses microsecond ticks
    tai_clock::rep ticks = 0;
    ticks = now.tv_sec * period::den;
    ticks += now.tv_nsec / 1000;
    return tai_clock::time_point(std::chrono::microseconds(ticks));
} else {
    throw std::runtime_error("reading CLOCK_TAI failed");
}
```

This code snippet fetches the current TAI time on my system.
Also, the code requires the TAI offset seconds to be configured correctly on the system.
Using this code part, I get the TAI time with an epoch starting at `1970-01-01 00:00:00.000`

Now it comes to the tricky part: I have to convert the epoch to meet my requirement.

So my quite silly approach was the following:
One day has `86400` TAI seconds.
From `1970-01-01 00:00:00.000` to `2004-01-01 00:00:00.000` are `12418` days.
Hence, I have to subtract `1072915200` seconds from my current TAI time to get the elapsed TAI seconds since `2004-01-01 00:00:00.000`.

So, my question is now: Can I correctly convert the epoch of my TAI time using this approach or is this trickier?

Comment: According to https://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?d1=01&m1=01&y1=1970&d2=01&m2=01&y2=2004&h1=0&i1=0&s1=0&h2=0&i2=0&s2=0 the amount of seconds are 1,072,915,200

Comment: So it is that easy? I only have to add the offset seconds to the UTC time and then subtract the 1,072,915,200 seconds to get the valid amount of elapsed TAI seconds?

Comment: It's a bit ugly, but it would do. No pitfalls there.

Comment: Yes, it's ugly. But nice to know that there are no pitfalls. However, can you suggest a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `boost` to get the current time , build a time object for `2004-01-01T00:00:00Z` and calculate the diff

```
#include "boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp"

boost::posix_time::ptime now(boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time());
boost::posix_time::ptime before(time_from_string("20040101T000000Z"));
long long diff = (now - before).total_microseconds();
```